# Какой HTML тэг для "иконки" меню использовать правильней? И какое у этой иконки должно быть расширение?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, img

[image: ЛУПА]

[image: Телефончик]

**Какой ХТМЛ тэг лучше всего использовать для элемента "лупа" и элемента "телефон"?**

---

И как правильно называются эти элементы? Иконка, значок, эмблема, изображение, штучка?
И мне никак не удается разобраться какое расширение использовать для таких элементов? ДжиПег, ПНГ или СВГ?
Не могли бы вы мне в объяснить что к чему, и почему по-вашему правильно делать именно так.
Спасибо, за то, что уделили мне ваше время.

Comment: Не думаю, что тут можно дать объективный ответ. Однако вы можете посмотреть как такие элементы сделаны на других сайтах.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше конечно использовать svg так как данный формат хорошо масштабитруется и мало весит. Svg вы можете разместить например в тег div нет никаких проблем.

Иногда бывают проблемы с размещением svg файлов многие незнают как их правильно разместить. Вы можете например скачать файл phone.svg и вызвать данный файл при помощи тега img

```
 <img class="svg" src="phone.svg" />
```

Но при таком подходе вы не сможете изменять цвет изображения. Так как в svg еще можно менять цвет изображения. В таком случае вы можете например использовать js код который трансформировал бы тег img в тег svg. Вот этот код вы можете использовать для этих целей

```
jQuery('.svg').each(function(){
    var $img = jQuery(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr('id');
    var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
    var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

    jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
        // получить тег svg
        var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

        // Добавить все ID которые были в теги img в svg
        if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
        }
        // Добавить все классы которые были в теги img в svg
        if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
        }

        // Удалить все ненужные xml теги
        $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

        // Заменить img на svg
        $img.replaceWith($svg);

    }, 'xml');

});
```

Но если вы сомневаетесь что выбрать, я могу порекомендовать вам готовые сборки иконок например https://icons8.com/line-awesome или https://fontawesome.com/

Comment: А что мешает вставить просто svg как текст? Зачем такое извращение с js'ом?

Comment: Валтер это снова ты) Ну ты и зануда) Зачем зачем чтобы разраб не мучился с кодом svg

Comment: Так и с обычным svg не мучаешься, зачем пресловутый тег img? его не стилизуешь без заплатки на js

Comment: А вы в js делаете мартышкин труд, меняя один тег на другой, и кто будет мучаться?

Comment: Какой труд? Мартышкин? Аха ха ха ты где так научился выражаться то) Ну ты и кадр) Я еще раз говорю для особеных svg код засоряет html.  При разработке визуально не удобно когда в html видишь svg код....

Comment: Так вы его выводите в дереве потом, при разработке вообще ни как не мешает. Ни как не засоряет. Как говориться плохому танцору... Он как обычный вложенный тег который можно свернуть если визуально напрягает

Comment: Смотри что лучше вот это <img src="phone.svg"/> или вот это <svg height="180" width="500">
  <polyline points="0,40 40,40 40,80 80,80 80,120 120,120 120,160" style="fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:4" />
</svg>

Comment: И это еще самый короткий код svg там бывает что и на десятки строк так что давай не будем умничать)

Comment: Лучше полный тег svg так браузер его будет обрабатывать как дерево а не грузить как картинку отдельно

Comment: А потом ещё вашим скриптом преобразовывать его в дереве в нормальный тег

Comment: А если ещё и у клиента по какой то причине отключен js то теперь сайт будет выглядеть не так как задумывал автор

Comment: Мда уж включи фантазию его можно и не грузить как изображение его можно запихнуть в любой тег да даже так <div class="svg" data-srs="/phone.svg"> ноу проблем. А преобразование как раз таки нужно для того чтобы получить полноценный svg код в дереве чтобы потом можно было через css назначать стили и т д. А то что у клиента будет отключен js во первых это мало вероятно ну а во вторых значит ему придется включить js)

Comment: Зачем мне делать лишнее? Если есть готовый тег svg? Зачем мне писать лишний исполняемый код что бы преобразовать простой тег который уже обрабатывается браузером?

Comment: Тебе точно не надо походу) А кому надо тот поймет) Так что можешь забить. Я не собираюсь повторять одно и то же по 100 раз мне за это не платят)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте svg. Они легко масштабируются/изменяются. Большинство иконок можно скачать в svg и разместить у себя в HTML коде как в примере.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/svg